# PHP Code breaking responsive navigation toggle on homepage

Tags: javascript, php, responsive-design, wordpress

I am having a problem with the responsive menu toggle not expanding on a site I am working on. Essentially when the site is resized below 768px the menu is replaced with a menu toggle that when clicked/tapped it should show the two options About & Shop. However when clicked nothing happens, it simply adds #navigation to the end of the URL.

I have managed to narrow down to one line of code that is for [**this plugin**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/3d-slider-slicebox/) in my index.php file.

```
<?php if(sb_slides_display()){sb_slides_display();} ?>
```

It is a simple WordPress site with WooCommerce using the theme mystile. Link: http://bit.ly/1dvdeb0

If I take out the above code the problem is solved but then of course the slider is no longer activated. Any ideas why or how it can be fixed?

Also, here is the code in context:

```
<?php
// File Security Check
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp' ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) && basename( __FILE__ ) == basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
    die ( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page!' );
}
?><?php
/**
 * Index Template
 *
 * Here we setup all logic and XHTML that is required for the index template, used as both the homepage
 * and as a fallback template, if a more appropriate template file doesn't exist for a specific context.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
    get_header();
    global $woo_options;

?>
    <?php if(sb_slides_display()){sb_slides_display();} ?>

    <?php if ( $woo_options[ 'woo_homepage_banner' ] == "true" ) { ?>

        <div class="homepage-banner">
            <?php
                if ( $woo_options[ 'woo_homepage_banner' ] == "true" ) { $banner = $woo_options['woo_homepage_banner_path']; }
                if ( $woo_options[ 'woo_homepage_banner' ] == "true" && is_ssl() ) { $banner = preg_replace("/^http:/", "https:", $woo_options['woo_homepage_banner_path']); }
            ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $banner; ?>" alt="" />
            <h1><span><?php echo $woo_options['woo_homepage_banner_headline']; ?></span></h1>
            <div class="description"><?php echo wpautop($woo_options['woo_homepage_banner_standfirst']); ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <div id="content" class="col-full <?php if ( $woo_options[ 'woo_homepage_banner' ] == "true" ) echo 'with-banner'; ?> <?php if ( $woo_options[ 'woo_homepage_sidebar' ] == "false" ) echo 'no-sidebar'; ?>">
```

Thanks in advance for any help it's greatly appreciated! :)

EDIT: JavaScript page from console error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fitVids' :

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* GENERAL SCRIPTS */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Fix dropdowns in Android
    if ( /Android/i.test( navigator.userAgent ) && jQuery( window ).width() > 769 ) {
        $( '.nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
    }

    // Table alt row styling
    jQuery( '.entry table tr:odd' ).addClass( 'alt-table-row' );

    // FitVids - Responsive Videos
    jQuery( ".post, .widget, .panel" ).fitVids();

    // Add class to parent menu items with JS until WP does this natively
    jQuery("ul.sub-menu").parents('li').addClass('parent');


    // Responsive Navigation (switch top drop down for select)
    jQuery('ul#top-nav').mobileMenu({
        switchWidth: 767,                   //width (in px to switch at)
        topOptionText: 'Select a page',     //first option text
        indentString: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'  //string for indenting nested items
    });



    // Show/hide the main navigation
    jQuery('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
      jQuery('#navigation').slideToggle('fast', function() {
        return false;
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });

    // Stop the navigation link moving to the anchor (Still need the anchor for semantic markup)
    jQuery('.nav-toggle a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Add parent class to nav parents
    jQuery("ul.sub-menu, ul.children").parents().addClass('parent');

});
```

Comment: If it's happening on the client it's more likely a javascript problem than a PHP one.  I'd guess that line is including some javascript that's causing an error.  If I look at the console in Chrome, there's an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fitVids'`.  I'd start by tracking down the cause of that.

Comment: @Hobo Thanks for the reply. I took a look and what you said is the same here. I managed to find the file that the error is talking about but unfortunately I don't really know much about javascript so I can't see what is wrong.

This is the snippet of code I think it's talking about and I have pasted the rest above. Maybe you could shed some light if something is standing out as wrong?

`// FitVids - Responsive Videos
 jQuery( ".post, .widget, .panel" ).fitVids();`

Comment: Try commenting out that line.  If you don't have any videos on your site, it's probably not being used (at a guess).  Otherwise, track it down (my guess is it's https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js), save it in your themes directory, and enqueue it in WordPress before `general.js` (ie have `general.js` depend on it).  It doesn't seem to be related to the plugin you linked - where did `general.js` come from?  Did you code it?  If so, why did you add that line?  If you copied it from somewhere, perhaps you just forgot to copy the fitvids source?

Comment: I'm not really sure where the fitvids code came from but I assume it was just part of the theme. I have just tried commenting it out but then I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mobileMenu'` I thing it is not actual fitvids that's causing the issue but instead the amount of times jQuery is being included in the page. A quick search lead me to `jQuery.noConflict();` but i'm not really understanding where to test this out.

Comment: Sorry - missed it before; fitvids and mobileMenu are both declared in third-party.js.  To my eye they look like they don't need `noConflict` - I think that's for when you want to use `$` instead of `jQuery`, but  your code uses `jQuery`, so should be OK.  I now think the problem is that jQuery is being included twice - try removing the second one (v1.8.2, from the Google CDN).  It's probably (judging by proximity) where your `slicebox.js` is included.

Comment: Thanks for that, I think this is indeed the problem. Now it is just a matter of finding how to remove it as it is in PHP and kills the slider if I take it out. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Hobo in the [comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304067/php-code-breaking-responsive-navigation-toggle-on-homepage/70924415#comment32169785_21304067):

> fitvids and mobileMenu are both declared in third-party.js. To my eye they look like they don't need noConflict - I think that's for when you want to use $ instead of jQuery, but your code uses jQuery, so should be OK. I now think the problem is that jQuery is being included twice - try removing the second one (v1.8.2, from the Google CDN). It's probably (judging by proximity) where your slicebox.js is included.